# XSLT show picture or show blank

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010

I have created a custom xslt style to display the news on my website. My issue is that some of my news have a banner and some of them don't. So how do I determine by using XSLT how to display the news with the banner or without it if it doens't have any?

I know what field contains the banner url. So I can imagine I have to loop through my news and then load the display form by the return value from some sort of if-statement that checks if the news has a banner or not.

I'm new to XSLT so how do I do this? Any help is appriciated.

Comment: The proper way to ask an XSLT question is to provide a complete (but as minimal as possible) XML document, the complete wanted result and to list any rules/constraints for the transformation. Please, do so, or else the quality of answers received will only match the quality of your question.

Comment: The classic XSLT way is pattern matching with pull style with niether `xsl:if` nor `xsl:choose` instructions like in the above answers. But without input sample we can't show you exactly how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not(empty(imageurlfield))">
    <!-- Display with image here -->
  </xsl:when>

  <xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- Display without image here -->
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: I get an error saying that 'empty()' is an unknown XSLT function?

Comment: `empty()` is an XPath/XSLT 2.0 function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xsl:if tag to test for some xpath existance:

```
<xsl:if test="./@banner">
    <p class="banner"><xsl:value-of select="./@banner" /></p>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: this will only work if the url it inside an attribute and will display the p-tag if the banner attribute contains an empty string.

Comment: @Chris: No. Efective Boolean Value of node sets is true unless it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify two templates, one for news items with a banner, and one without.

```
<xsl:template match="newsitem[banner]">
  <!-- pattern for news items with a banner -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newsitem">
  <!-- pattern for news items without a banner -->
</xsl:template>
```

The above example assumes news items are contained in an element named `newsitem`, with a child element `banner` containing data about the banner, if there is one. The second template here is superceded by the first for `newsitem` elements that contain a `banner` child.